# R Count for each value how many other numbers in my vector are under a specified thresold

Tags: r

I've a vector with about 50,000 numbers in it. I want to compute for each value how many other numbers in my vector are <= a specified thresold. And then return the maximum value.

Now I'm doing

```
n <- 50000
s <- 100000
win <- 1000 # my thresold
pos <- sample(s,n,replace=T) 
m <- max(sapply(pos,function(x){sum(abs(pos-x)<=win)}))
```

But it's very very slow ... And I need to do that N=1,000,000 times (for a simulation). Any idea to speed up this thing ?

Here's an example of what I want :

Let's say

```
pos <-c(2,6,20,23,24,56,64,75,95,100)
```

for each value in pos I can compute how many number of the vector are at a minimal distance of win=20.
So :

```
2 : 2,6,20
6 : 2,6,20,23,24
20: 2,6,20,23,24
23: 6,20,23,24
24: 6,20,23,24
56: 56,64,75
64: 56,64,75
75: 56,64,75,95
95: 75,95,100
100: 95,00
```

And I want the maximum length of these subsets = 5 (group 6 and 20)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in the code (a bracket not in the good position). Now it works

Comment: @mtoto They want per each number in the `pos` vector all the values around it (both smaller and larger) within the +-20 interval. Then check which value has the largest group around it.

Comment: Maybe `findInterval(pos+win,pos) - findInterval(pos-win,pos)`? Got some problems on the extrema, but it should give how many numbers are between `pos-win` and `pos+win` for each `pos` (note that `pos` must be sorted).

Comment: @nicola Thanks that's perfect ! :)

Comment: A small correction to @nicola solution should take care of the edges `findInterval(pos+win,pos) - findInterval(pos-win,pos+1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Great idea. With `findInterval(pos+win,pos) - findInterval(pos-win,pos*(1+.Machine$double.eps))` one can maybe handle also double values for `pos`.

Comment: @nicola you should definitely post this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#you need to sort the vector before 
#(take a copy if you don't want to lose the original)
pos<-sort(pos)
findInterval(pos+win,pos) - findInterval(pos-win,pos*(1+.Machine$double.eps))
```

The last line should give you the number of elements between `pos-win` and `pos+win` for each element of `pos`. The factor `1+.Machine$double.eps` is needed to deal with edge cases (tx to @DavidArenburg).